# When do I use `useDispatch` & `useSelector` hooks with `RTK Query`?

Tags: react-hooks, redux-toolkit, rtk-query

I've started using `Redux Toolkit` with `RTK Query` for developing a client-side application that relies on API requests for data. However, I've come across a dilemma. Following the `Redux Toolkit` documentation, it's recommended to use `RTK Query` in container components and then pass the fetched data to presentational components. Yet, with this approach, I find myself not utilizing slices or `Redux` state at all. What would be the best approach in this scenario, and when should I use the `useSelector` and `useDispatch` hooks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the documentation we can use rtk query to fetch the data and pass the data to component and presentational layers where. but there are few scenario where you will need to cache the data in redux store and use it throughout the app, in that case slice, useSelector, useDispatch hook comes in the picture. for example while user sign in, you can use useDispatch hook to store the user data in redux store with user slice. further you can use user data directly using useSelector throughout the app

```
export const useAppDispatch = () => useDispatch<AppDispatch>();
export const useAppSelector: TypedUseSelectorHook<RootState> = useSelector;
```

i.e auth layer

```
const dispatch = useAppDispatch();
  const { data: userData, isLoading } = useGetUserQuery();

useEffect(()=>{
dispatch(setUserInfo(userData ));
},[])
```

and you can use store data throughout the app with useAppSelector

```
const userData = useAppSelector((state: RootState) => state.user);
```